# Definitions file for simple js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I am trying to make a DefinitelyTyped definition file for a small npm commonjs library as some typescript practice. The module's exports looks like this:

```
module.exports = useNative() ? NativeCustomEvent :
// IE >= 9
'undefined' !== typeof document && 'function' === typeof 
document.createEvent ? function CustomEvent (type, params) {...} 
// IE < 9 
: function CustomEvent(type, params) {...}
```

where

`useNative` is a boolean function, and `CustomEvent` returns an event e and `var NativeCustomEvent = global.CustomEvent`

I just want to write a clean .d.ts file for this simple module. I am just getting a bit lost with trying to do it. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update:

So i have `/node-modules/custom-event` (the js module)
and added to `/node-modules/@types/` a folder called `/custom-event` where I added a `custom-event.d.ts`

code so far:

```
declare module "custom-event" {
    function CustomEvent(type: any, params: any): any
    export = CustomEvent
}
```

Comment: Seems like it should be `NativeCustomEvent | (type: ?, params: ?) => ...`

Comment: @unional in the .d.ts? I'm just trying to workout how to write the definition file for the above .js

Comment: Yes, in the d.ts. You will need to use @types/node as for the `NativeCustomEvent == global.CustomEvent`. Check out the handbook on the basic structure of d.ts.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates.html

Comment: @unional so shouldn't i be trying to export the CustomEvent function though? the .js is a CustomEvent polyfill

Comment: I've been reading up on it all day, but feel I just need to see an example for this script for everything to hang together

Comment: Then it is just exporting CustomEvent

Comment: Yes, or better just use the node's `CustomEvent`

Comment: But then I get errors when I try to reference it: `import { CustomEvent } from "custom-event"` gives: `Could not find a declaration file for module`

Comment: It is a commonJs module?  You should not do named export.  Use import - require syntax

Comment: Put the file in custom-typings folder and include it in your tsconfig.json

Comment: now doing `import CustomEvent = require("custom-event")` and added the module declare to my `Manualtypings.d.ts` which is in my `tsconfig`. But still getting: `Cannot find type definition file for 'custom-event'`

Comment: that's what I tried originally but thought I had to create separate declaration file and started reading about DefinitelyTyped..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider DT, you can do this:

```
// custom-typings/custom-event.d.ts
declare module "custom-event" {
  export = CustomEvent
}

// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": ...
  }
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "custom-typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can i not just include the declare module in a `manualTypings.d.ts` file with other module definitions and have: `"files" : [ "manualTypings.d.ts"]` in `tsconfig.json` and surely ideally i should not edit the `package.json` of a node module i installed?

Comment: The package.json means you will do `npm install @types/node`. If your library simply use `custom-event`, you can do `npm install -D @types/node`.

Comment: I've eliminated the typescript errors like this, but when I import CustomEvent = require("custom-event"); to my app.ts main function, the polyfill is not getting implemented when i call: `document.addEventListener("auth", (event: AuthEvent) => {
    withAccount(event.detail);
   });` where AuthEvent extends CustomEvent. Thanks for all your help by the way. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Just checking, you did `npm i 'custom-event'`, right? Check how it is being used. Maybe not `import CustomEvent = require('custom-event')`?

Comment: im using yarn so i did `yarn add custom-event`

Comment: here is the npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-event. here is some pure typescript implementation https://gist.github.com/markrendle/0c3876b0637f79802713 and then there is definitelytyped.. Feeling so lost which i should use and when and why i can't seem to get any of them to work.

Comment: It should be working. Can you create a demo repo on github? Maybe I can take a look.